# Laravel Eager loading of a relationship bettween two models causes a relationship between other models return wrong results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have two Eloquent models named Question and Answer with **one to many** relationship between them (one question has many answers). The hasMany relationship in Question.php is called **answers**.

I also have a User and a Company model with a **many to many** relationship between them which uses a pivot model, defined this way:

User.php

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class)
        ->using(CompanyUser::class);
}
```

Company.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
        ->using(CompanyUser::class);
}
```

When I retreive a question and lazy load its answers:

```
Question::find(58)->answers;
```

Everything is okay. The problem comes when I use eager loading:

```
Question::with('answers')->get();
```

Something strange happens. In the answers() relationship method of the Question model, I need to get the current user's first company in order to modify the relationship:

```
auth()->user()->companies->first();
```

Most of the users in my application have one company attaches to them, when using eager loading though **auth()->user()->companies** returns not one, but 134 companies even though in the database I have only 5 companies and the current user belongs to only one. When I dumped the contents of the **auth()->user()->companies** collection I saw that the first company model is exists 130 times and the other 4 companies are also included.

This happens only in the **answers()** method and only when using eager loading. Any ideas why?

Environment:

- Laravel version: 6.20.6
- PHP version: 8.0.1
- Apache: 2.4.26
- DB: 10.1.27-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get more information on the problem. What I normally do is insert ddd() and check the queries tab to see what queries Laravel is using to get the data. This might shed some more light on the problem.